# Проблемы с Notifications

Tags: swift, spritekit

Здравствуйте!
Есть функция, которая ставит игру на паузу.

```
func pauseTheGame()
{
self.scene?.isPaused = true
//так же здесь прописано несколько других параметров, типа появление надписи, кнопок и т.д.
}
```

Данная функция вызывается в двух случаях.

1) Когда игрок нажимает на кнопку паузы во время игры.

2) Когда приложение отправляется в бэкграунд.

Но есть одна небольшая проблема с Notifications. Небольшой пример кода:

Из AppDelegate

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)
{
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "goToBackground"), object: self)
}
```

Из игровой сцены:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameScene.pauseTheGame), name: NSNotification.Name("goToBackground"), object: nil)
```

1. Первая проблема заключается в том, что когда приложение сворачивается, игра ставится на паузу, т.е. вызывается функция и все идет своим чередом.
   Но когда приложение становится снова активным, то игра САМА выключает паузу и игра продолжается. То есть значение паузы каким-то образом само меняется на значение "false". Хотя остальные вещи, такие как кнопки и текст, остаются на месте. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?
2. Как я уже сказал выше. Функция паузы вызывается либо при нажатии на кнопку, либо при сворачивании. Хотелось бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы функция не вызывалась дважды. То есть если игрок нажал на паузу, а после этого еще и свернул приложение. То есть функция вызывается дважды. И приходится два раза нажимать кнопочку "PLAY".

Comment: покажите что у вас в pauseTheGame

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: магия короче. я так понимаю проект не ваш и где то есть куски кода о которых вы не знаете. в частности две паузы с последующим двойным нажатием play это кто то до вас намутил. если хотите выложите весь приект, что то будем думать

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, у Вас одна и таже функция и ставит на паузу, и продолжает игру. Решений здесь - как фантазия разгуляется.

1. Вы можете разнести в разные функции паузу и старт игры.
2. Можно разнести в разные функции вызов паузы пользователем и вызов паузы уходом в фон.
3. Можно добавить флаг, что паузу вызывает пользователь и использовать его
4. Можно добавить флаг, что паузу вызывает уход в фон и использовать это.
5. Использовать п.3 + п.4

Comment: Нет, Вы, не правильно поняли. Боюсь, что, Вы, прочитали вопрос не внимательно.